# FFMPEG CUDA Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to convert an FFMPEG RTMP source, resize it, and pass it to another RTMP source. My command is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -hide_banner -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 8 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/xxxxxx -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 8000k -bufsize 8000k -g 60 -r 30 -s 640x360 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/xxxxx_360
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/xxxxxxxx':
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: false
  Duration: N/A, start: 1461.149000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24.42 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
[aac @ 0x56096f201540] Qavg: 1955.047
[aac @ 0x56096f201540] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Any guidance on the conversion error?

Comment: What format is your input stream (likely MP4 or MOV)?

Comment: The format of the input stream is an MP4

Comment: I don't know if MP4 and FLV are compatible but make sure input and output are. You use `-f flv` on your output stream, but not your input, so maybe try to specify the format with `-f`. Same with video/audio codecs. Your specify `libx264` for your output, but maybe is your input encoded with a different codec (H.264, H.265). You can copy codecs with `-c:copy`

Comment: You can also try the `-filter_complex` flag for specific values for both input and output (e.g. scale).